# SQL QUERY WITH A CASE IN WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a query - to cover a case :- where I want to check if any misc value present for a code_id (a input vairable) if not then use code_id as default value (i.e OTH).

something like

```
select MISC_FLAGS  
from systemcode 
where rec_type = 'C' 
   and code_type = 'SAN' 
   and  CODE_ID = 'HT';
```

If no value for this then it should return result for:

```
select MISC_FLAGS  
from systemcode 
where rec_type = 'C' 
   and code_type = 'SAN' 
   and  CODE_ID = 'OTH';
```

Comment: Please, provide sample data and desired output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query

```
select MISC_FLAGS  from systemcode where rec_type = 'C' and code_type = 'SAN' and CODE_ID = 'HT' or (
CODE_ID = 'OTH' and TABLE_ID not in (select TABLE_ID   from systemcode where rec_type = 'C' and code_type = 'SAN' and CODE_ID = 'HT') 
)
```

Comment: thanks a lot arlabbafi. I got the context .  I quickly tried the solution but not able to run it as it is throwing me an error  - that table_id is not a valid identifier   and If I am trying to replace it with another identifier of the table it is giving me two values for both input variables (HT and OTH) ... where as I need OTH value only if HT is not there

Comment: you should replace TABLE_ID with name of your table's primary key

Answer (score 0):

This could be one option; read comments within code.

As I ran it in SQL*Plus, I used substitution variable; depending on how you do it, it might be a bind variable (`:par_code_id`) instead; or, if it is a procedure/function, you'd just use just `par_code_id`.

```
SQL> with systemcode (misc_flags, rec_type, code_type, code_id) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 'MSC', 'C', 'SAN', 'OTH' from dual union all
  4     select 'ABC', 'C', 'SAN', 'TT'  from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    -- MX = 1 if :PAR_CODE_ID exists in SYSTEMCODE table
  8    -- MX = 0 if :PAR_CODE_ID does not exist in SYSTEMCODE table
  9    (select nvl(max(1), 0) mx
 10     from systemcode
 11     where exists (select null from systemcode
 12                   where code_id = '&&par_code_id'
 13                  )
 14     )
 15  select s.misc_flags
 16  from systemcode s cross join temp t
 17  where s.rec_type = 'C'
 18    and s.code_type = 'SAN'
 19    -- depending on MX value, select either row(s) that match :PAR_CODE_ID or 'OTH'
 20    and s.code_id = case when t.mx = 1 then '&&par_code_id'
 21                         else 'OTH'
 22                    end;
Enter value for par_code_id: HT          --> doesn't exist, so use OTH

MIS
---
MSC

SQL> undefine par_code_id
SQL> /
Enter value for par_code_id: TT         --> it exists

MIS
---
ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use conditional aggregation to select `OTH` and `CODE_ID` of your input in different columns. Then select one of the columns depending on the presence of specified `CODE_ID`.

> ```
> create table systemcode (
>   MISC_FLAGS,
>   rec_type,
>   code_type,
>   CODE_ID
> ) as
> select 'HT', 'C', 'SAN', 'HT' from dual union all
> select 'OTH', 'C', 'SAN', 'OTH' from dual
> ```

> ```
> select decode(
>   /*If the specified code is present*/
>   max(decode(code_id, 'HT', code_id)),
>   'HT',
>   /*then select a value for that code*/
>   max(decode(code_id, 'HT', MISC_FLAGS)),
>   /*else - select default value*/
>   max(decode(code_id, 'OTH', MISC_FLAGS))
> ) as code_id
> from systemcode
> where code_id in ('HT', 'OTH')
> ```
>
> ```
> | CODE_ID |
> | :------ |
> | HT      |
> ```

> ```
> select decode(
>   max(decode(code_id, 'AAA', code_id)),
>   'AAA',
>   max(decode(code_id, 'AAA', MISC_FLAGS)),
>   max(decode(code_id, 'OTH', MISC_FLAGS))
> ) as code_id
> from systemcode
> where code_id in ('AAA', 'OTH')
> ```
>
> ```
> | CODE_ID |
> | :------ |
> | OTH     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=664b9be7aa195990253346f1895157da)*

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a single row to return for each code, you can use:

```sql
SELECT misc_flags
FROM   (
  SELECT misc_flags 
  FROM   systemcode 
  WHERE  rec_type  = 'C' 
  AND    code_type = 'SAN' 
  AND    code_id   IN ('HT', 'OTH')
  ORDER BY code_id ASC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;
```

If there can be multiple rows:

```sql
SELECT misc_flags
FROM   (
  SELECT misc_flags,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY code_id ASC) AS rnk
  FROM   systemcode 
  WHERE  rec_type  = 'C' 
  AND    code_type = 'SAN' 
  AND    code_id   IN ('HT', 'OTH')
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Comment: `order by nullif(code_id, 'OTH') nulls last` will be more flexible as it doesn't imply input code to be "before" `OTH` (for example, `ZZZ`)

Comment: @astentx The `WHERE` filter on `code_id` eliminates the need for anything like that.

Comment: I'm sorry, still cannot get how it would. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=341ac829a274d00ee69b7b8d954140ef).

Comment: @astentx You have changed the requirements of the question. In that case, use `DESC` instead of `ASC` in the ordering.

Comment: Requirement in the OP: "want to check if any misc value present for a code_id (**a input vairable**)"

Comment: @astentx It can still only be two possible values by the `WHERE` filter (if it is outside those two values then the query will return zero rows) and they can be sorted using `ASC` or `DESC`; yes, it could be done via a function but it is not necessary.